# Cannot access git remote branches with shell but can with GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm having an issue with Git that I never faced before.
I am now working on Azure Dev Ops to push content to a Git repository.
I have never worked with it before, so consider me a complete noob.

**I need to be connected to a VPN to access Azure Dev Ops**.
I cannot access the remote server, meaning I cannot fetch, pull or push with the shell (which I like to use over a UI).
I get the following error every time I try to fetch (with my vpn connected):

> fatal: unable to access 'https://companyname@dev.azure.com/companyname/groupname/_git/reponame/': Failed to connect to dev.azure.com port 443: Connection refused

When I try to fetch without the vpn. I get the credentials manager window asking for my account login and password but it cannot go through with the authentication because the VPN is not connected.

Now, here's where things start to complicate.
I've managed to work so far because I can fetch, pull and push with the GitHub Desktop app.
It is the only UI that works. I've tried others, but this one is the only one that managed to fetch from the remote somehow.

I have looked in the app logs and I see this command as soon as I hit the "fetch" button:

> git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin

Although, this command does not work in a shell.
I get the same error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://companyname@dev.azure.com/companyname/groupname/_git/reponame/': Failed to connect to dev.azure.com port 443: Connection refused

Here is my config (git config --list):

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
credential.helper=
credential.helper=C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git\ Credential\ Manager\ Core/git-credential-manager-core.exe
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
user.username=My Username
user.name=My Name
user.email=My work email (and email used in my azure account)
commit.template=C:/Users/name/Documents/git_message.txt
alias.st=status
alias.ci=commit
alias.lg=log --graph --date=relative --pretty=tformat:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%an %ad)%Creset'
alias.oops=commit --amend --no-edit
alias.review-local=!git lg @{push}..
alias.li=log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)'
alias.lol=log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
alias.lola=log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
alias.pullall=fetch --all && pull
alias.fp=fetch --prune
alias.ba=branch -a
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/name/Documents/Workspace_companyname/projectname
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
submodule.active=.
remote.origin.url=https://companyname@dev.azure.com/companyname/groupname/_git/reponame
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Does anybody have an idea of what could be causing this issue ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below possible solutions to fix this issue.

1, Run below commands to configure the proxy setting for git.

`git config --global http.proxy https://user:password@proxy.com:port`

Then Create an environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` on your local machine. And set its value to `https://:@proxy:port`.

See [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/4833/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error.html) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/419774/proxy-authentication-with-git-and-gcm-from-devazur.html) for more information.

2, You can also try below solution that modifying the git config file to include the credentials in the remote url:

Replace the your `companyname` with the [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

`remote.origin.url=https://PersonalAccessToken@dev.azure.com/companyname/groupname/_git/reponame`

```
git remote add origin -f  "https://PersonalAccessToken@dev.azure.com/companyname/groupname/_git/reponame"
```

3, You can also try using SSH to connect to your azure devops git.

Please check out below document for more information.

[Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

Comment: I get the following message when setting the proxy like in the first solution: fatal: unable to access 'https://companyname@dev.azure.com/companyname/groupname/_git/reponame/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Comment: With the second solution. I get the same error as before. And SSH was actually the first thing I've tried but I get a connection refused every time even though I have set up my SSH public key in Azure Dev Ops.